# How to recover system gcc compiler on centos 6

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am running centos 6 on a cluster. I installed the latest gcc-8.2.0.  and made a link "ln -sf /usr/bin/gcc-8.2 gcc".
I did the same for g++ and gfortran.
I wanted to reinstall gcc-8.2.0 and went ahead to

```
make clean
```

in the gcc-8.2 directory.
When I try

```
./configure
```

I get that C compiler cannot create executables
The links I made are broken.
The system gcc-4.4.7 cannot be found

```
which gcc
```

gives no gcc

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

gives gcc is already installed.
I tried to install an rpm, which fails because of dependencies.
I have pg compilers installed in /opt/pgi
When I configure with

```
CC=/path to/pgi/bin/pgcc FC=/path to/pgi/bin/pgfortran ./configure
```

I still get C compiler cannot create executables
I tried the following c++ programm

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

With the command

```
/opt/pgi/linux_86_64/12.08/bin/pgcpp hello.cpp -o hello
```

It gives compilation error that float.h not found. On another linux PC with working gcc, the program works with the command

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello
```

I will appreciate any assistance to either find the systemgcc or use pg compilers to compile gcc if possible

I admit it is a big mess which will require OS reinstallation and reconfiguration. But then I did

```
sudo yum install compat-gcc-34
```

Now I have gcc34 and configure of gcc-8.2 goes through without "c compiler cannot create executables". (Note that the ./configure referred to in earlier post was actually

```
../gcc_8_2_release/configure
```

inside "gcc_8_2_release_build, so gcc was not being built in its source directory.
The problem I have now is with make, which needs g++, giving error

```
uint_t(64) or int_t(64) not found.
```

Thanks all who have gone through this post, for your patience.
Any assistance will be appreciated.

Here is how I got out of this mess.
With the following two commands

```
sudo yum install compat-gcc-34-c++
sudo yum install compat-gcc-34-g77
```

I was able to install the older version of gcc, c++ and g77. Then I was able to build gcc-8.2.
Now I have a functional system with the latest gcc, yes it may need re-installation/re-configuring but it is fully functional.
I have learnt a lot and very much appreciate the comments and guidelines of @Basile. However, at one point he was rather negative and discouraging.
But thanks to my belief and perseverance, and more importantly browsing the knowledge shared by others, I have been able to recover what I was beginning  to be convinced was a lost cause.
Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried `yum reinstall gcc` ?

Comment: In the future; when you want a newer compiler than the system one on a RedHat/CentOS system, consider using the "devtoolset" packages. See fx [Product Documentation for Red Hat Developer Toolset 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/7/). Devtoolset nicely solves the problem of preserving the system compiler while also giving you access to newer tools that are compatible with everything built with the system compiler and fully supported by RedHat.

Answer (score 3):

This is more a sysadmin question than a programming one.

My recommendations:

- don't mess your `/usr/bin/`. Leave your package manager `yum` to fill it -and never add anything inside it without `yum` ; so remove manually any symlinks you made there (by mistake)
- reinstall the old system `gcc` 4.4 and `g++` 4.4 (using `yum`)
- rebuild your GCC 8 from scratch from its source code. Configure it with `--program-suffix=-8` (but no `--prefix`, or a `--prefix=$HOME/soft/` if you don't have root access). So it will install `/usr/local/bin/gcc-8` and `/usr/local/bin/g++-8`  etc... (or, if you have given `--prefix=$HOME/soft/` , a `$HOME/soft/bin/gcc-8` etc...)
- create a `$HOME/bin/` if you don't have already one
- be sure to have `$HOME/bin/` *early* in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (before `/usr/bin/`)
- add a symlink `ln -sv /usr/local/bin/gcc-8 $HOME/bin/gcc` and likewise for `g++` etc..

Then, when you type `gcc` you are getting that symlink to `/usr/local/bin/gcc-8` etc.

If you cannot write to `/usr/local/` (e.g. because you don't have root permission...) you could pass `--prefix=$HOME/soft/` to GCC 8 `.../configure` then replace `/usr/local/` above with `$HOME/soft/`

If you are the sysadmin and can write to `/usr/local/` and have to set up things for many users: add a symlink `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-8 /usr/local/bin/gcc` etc and ask your users to put `/usr/local/bin/` in *their* `$PATH`  before `/usr/bin/`

BTW, notice that it is *explicitly* documented that GCC 8 (or others) need to be built *outside* of its source tree: in [Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) you can read:

> First, we **highly recommend** that GCC be built into a separate directory from the sources which does not reside within the source tree.

(the "highly recommend" should be considered as a polite way to say "you absolutely should")

So your `./configure` was another mistake.

It could happen that **you messed up your system** more seriously than you thought (and perhaps you need to reinstall, or to call Redhat support).

PS. I don't know Redhat (used it only in the previous century). My favorite distro is Debian/testing or Debian/unstable (and my computers are desktops, not clusters).

Comment: Thank you @Basile for the very useful hints. My problem is that sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ says gcc is already installed, and sudo yum install gcc-4.4 says gcc-4.4 does not exist

Comment: Yes, you need to forcibly *reinstall* `gcc`. I am not familiar enough with `yum` to help. But how to do that should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ; if you don't know how to *reinstall* `gcc` you could consider reinstalling your entire system. In other words, you have messed your system quite badly

Comment: Problem has been solved, see edit at the end of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by the following commands

```
sudo yum install compat-gcc-34-c++
sudo yum install compat-gcc-34-g77
```

Once this older version of gcc is installed, the latest version, gcc-8.2 was built and the system is no longer messed terribly. It is very healthy and fit.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You could have removed the silly symlink you created and then done `yum reinstall gcc gcc-c++` instead, to restore the original system compiler. Don't replace the system compiler, see Basile's answer.

Comment: Your clever answer does not work, my silly solution works! There is no silly link. The other one was saying my system is messed up, what messed up? i can have as many compiler versions as I want. this forum is for sharing information , not identifying who is more silly, that can go to another forum.