# cannot revise gcc version even after installing the new and deleting the old one

Tags: linux, gcc, centos

I work on CentOS 5.5 and my computer used gcc-4.1.2 until now, and under `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/` there were 2 indexes: 4.1.1 and 4.1.2. For using some softwares I must update the gcc.

But after I installed gcc-4.7.0 from the downloaded gcc-4.7.0.tar.gz (I did not use yum because when I tried it all servers told me that I had the latest version which was certainly not true, and perhaps this was also caused by the problem I now face with), the `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0/` was created just like the 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 index, so under `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/` there were 3 indexes: 4.1.1, 4.1.2 and 4.7.0. And under `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0/` there were 6 indexes:

```
bin include lib lib64 libexex share
```

It looked like that 4.7.0 was successfully installed but when I ran

```
gcc --version
```

the result was still

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is 
NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I also ran

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0 40
```

to raise the priority of 4.7.0, and when I ran

```
update-alternatives --config gcc
```

it said

```
There is 1 program that provides 'gcc'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

And I printed 1, all it looked like that 4.7.0 was selected as the default gcc, but when I ran `gcc --version`, the result was not changed! Still 4.1.2.

After that I even removed all 4.1.2 gcc and its related programs by `rpm -e` and deleted the index, but the result of `gcc --version` became

```
-bash: gcc: command not found.
```

It didn’t change when I reinstalled the 4.7.0.

After all, when I looked for the links of `/usr/bin/gcc/` I found

```
/usr/bin/gcc -> /etc/alternatives/gcc
```

and link of `/etc/alternatives/gcc` was

```
/etc/alternatives/gcc -> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0
```

this should be the result of my running the `update-alternatives` line, so it has worked. It did make the link to 4.7.0. So why didn’t this link call 4.7.0 in the end? I can’t find out.

I even made the direct link to 4.7.0 then:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0 /usr/bin/gcc
```

however this still didn’t work.

I am very confused with it. I will be grateful for your help. Thank you very much!

p.s. Thank Basile Starynkevitch very much for noticing me to make these explanations:

1. I have `/usr/bin/` in my PATH, so this should be OK.
2. I am teached that `/usr/bin/gcc/` should be linked to an executable but not index, so the link to 4.7.0 is wrong. But could anyone tell me which executable to link to, or which executable is `/usr/bin/` linked to in a common computer? This may very likely lead to the solution to the problem.
3. I cannot run `configure` one more time because `configure` itself requires gcc but now it is not found. So I'm afraid the problem cannot be fixed by that.

Comment: `/etc/alternatives/gcc -> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0`?  Shouldn't it be `/etc/alternatives/gcc -> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0/gcc` ?

Comment: but there is not that index there. As I said, under the `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0/` there were 6 indexes: `bin include lib lib64 libexex share`(sorry, that line was hard to see and now I have edited it)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). You could have some `$HOME/bin/` in it.

Restore your system's `gcc` (so undo all the mess you have done). Then run `which gcc` and `gcc -v` to understand what is it exactly.

If you compile [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) from its source code (as [distributed](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) by the FSF), choose a recent version, e.g. [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) in fall 2018.

Read carefully about [installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/). Compile it outside of its source code. Be aware of the many [configure](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) options. I suggest to consider configuring it with some `--program-suffix` option (such as `--program-suffix=-8`) and then adding symlinks (e.g. `$HOME/bin/gcc` -> `/usr/local/bin/gcc-8`) appropriately.

> ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0 /usr/bin/gcc

it is wrong. Since `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0/` is some internal directory, and  `/usr/bin/gcc` has to be an executable.

You probably don't need to run `update-alternatives`, but you do need to add (cleverly) something in a directory mentioned in your `PATH`

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298991/841108) to a similar question.

#### after edits in the question

You need first **to clean up the mess** you did under `/usr/` (in particular in `/usr/bin/` which you should never change without your package system). Remove all the things you added under `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/lib/`. Then re-install *forcibly* and *explicitly* appropriate *system* `gcc` packages (using `yum` or some other package manager).

> I have /usr/bin/ in my PATH, so this should be OK.

Probably not. My recommendation is to have `$HOME/bin/` and `/usr/local/bin/` *early* in your `PATH` (so *before* `/usr/bin/`; you might need to edit `~/.bashrc` to change your `PATH` setting) and to add your new `gcc`, as something like `gcc-8` (if you compile  [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) from its source code), there. If you want a system wide installation, have some `/usr/local/bin/gcc-8` program. If you want a personal installation, have some `$HOME/bin/gcc-8` program (both could be absolute symlinks to somewhere else).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have some questions: 1. I do have /usr/bin/ in the PATH so it should be OK. 2. Is there any hint to where I should link /usr/bin/gcc? Because I do not know which executable to pick in the 4.7.0 index... 3. I am afraid that I cannot reconfigure the 4.7.0 because the running of configure itself requires the gcc and after I deleted the 4.1.2 now the command is not found...

Comment: Put that in your question